# Is it advisable to drop existing and create a new index without bringing down application?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I am running an application with a large SQL Server database. It may contain more than 500 millions of records on several tables.

I would like to drop an existing index and create a new index. Note that two indexes are completely different.

Here is my question: 
Is it advisable to drop and create new index without bringing down my application?

Any advice?

Comment: You may have more luck at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: >>>I would like to drop an existing index and create a new index<<< Is it clustered o nonclustered?

Comment: Both indexes are non-clustered (old and new)

Comment: This is a simple question with a very complex answer. It depends on concurrency, amount of rows, how the current index is being used, how the new index is gonna be used, and many other factors. I suggest creating the new index first, then monitoring if the old one is being used.

Comment: @Noah, is your question answered? If so, consider to mark it as such one.

Comment: I dropped the existing and created the new index without bringing down the application. And the performance was improved immediately. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it advisable to drop existing and create a new index without
>   bringing down application?

It depends, it can be that:

- non-clustered index to be  built on table that is not actively in use
- you have Enterprise Edition
- creation of index without waiting to next maintenance windows will provide benefits to some business process.

In this case you `can accept` creation of the index with option ONLINE=ON:

```
CREATE INDEX i1 ON Table1 (Column1) WITH (ONLINE=ON)
```

Otherwise, consider to wait till next maintenance window and do it offline way by stopping app. Also consider some performance hit during index creation either: via online or offline mode